# Function Definitions Size does not fit on xcode

Tags: xcode, swift4, xcode9, code-documentation

Possibly a dumb question, however, I would love to know if there is a way in `Xcode9` to expand the `function definitions`.

As shown below, most of the text does not fit properly (unable to read) even when both `Navigator` and `Utilities` Bars are closed in `Xcode`. I can read the full text of the method if I hover over the function and pause there for a while. this is very time consuming.

Thank you in advance and sorry for such a dumb question.

[image]

Comment: Not dumb at all. I’m afraid the way it behaves is exactly as you say. File an enhancement request with Apple!

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is there a way to expand the window? I notice sometimes the definitions open fully stretched (shows the content perfectly) , but most of the time is a pain in the Neck.